# connect libre calc to postgresql

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, postgresql

I want to connect my libre calc sheet to postgresql so that it gets updated automatically after some interval.

So, I click **sheet > Link to external Data**, then the connector appears,

[image]

I have entered the correct URL(I think so).

But the **OK** button remains disabled. I cannot click OK. I also don't know the **available tables/ranges** option.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That menu option is not for databases.  From [Linking_to_external_data in OOo3 User Guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Linking_to_external_data):

> You can insert tables from HTML documents, and data located within named ranges from an OpenOffice.org Calc or Microsoft Excel spreadsheet, into a Calc spreadsheet (To use other data sources, including database files in OOo Base, see [Linking to registered data sources](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Linking_registered_data)).

This question was also answered at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6190/how-to-link-a-calc-spreadsheet-to-a-base-database/ with a link to step-by-step instructions.